# ajax request concatenate jason in data object

Tags: ajax

i have ajax request and i call the api in the action and in js i create vars input's
my api need to get json so
i'll try to concatenate jason in data object but i get syntax errors

what am i doing wrong?

thanks for the help

```
<script>
function postForm() {

    var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    var phone = document.forms["form"]["phone"].value.replace("-", "");
    var email = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;

    if (name === "" || phone === "" || email === "") {
        window.alert("עלייך למלא את כל השדות");
        return false;
    }

    if (!validatePhone(phone)) {
        window.alert("הכנס מספר טלפון תקין");
        return false;
    }

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        window.alert("כתובת המייל שהזנת אינה חוקית");
        return false;
    }

    if (!validateName(name)) {
        window.alert("הכנס שם באותיות רווחים");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
     $.ajax({
          url: $('form').attr('action'),
          method: "get",
          dataType:'json',
          data: {"name": "name", "phone": "phone", "email: email", "details": "details"},
          success: function () {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function() {
              window.alert("משהו לא הלך כשורה");
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: what was the `error`?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`
 i think its the concatenate on the data object